# EmberJS - Server side generated variable

Tags: ember.js

We are building our front-end application in EmberJS. We do several calls to a service (via Ajax) that requires a token.

This token is created by another request to this service.

All the clients will use the same token, so, ideally, it would be great to generate this token in the server side and provide this value in a global variable to all the clients.

Is it possible to do it in EmberJS, for example, when the nodeJS starts the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that will hold the variable in its state and when the application starts make a request to the server in order to get the generated value.

I have followed a similar technique only with more complex variables that may change every time the application starts.

This could work as follows:

Create an application route. The application route runs when the application starts. In the application route make the request to get the data from the server and store it to your service for later usage.

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/e02f2decca9be3fd24025e53ce357015?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) is a twiddle demonstrating this solution.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.

Comment: But, where am I supposed to include server side code in EmberJS?

Does EmberJS provide a file to run initilization codes when the application starts in server?

In my tests, I verified that the 'app.js' runs in the client side (I can see the ajax call in the network tab in chrome).

Thanks again for you help.

Comment: I enhanced my answer and provided an example as well. Please take a look.